# length() of two vectors give different values, but when checking using a for loop, the vectors have the same length

Tags: r

I have two double vectors named `ages` and `taus` that are supposed to have the same length of 6078 (so I can put them into a data.table). When I check with `length()`

```
length(ages)
# 6078

length(taus)
# 6062
```

I attempted to use a for loop to iterate through both in order to check for missing vector elements:

```
age_counter <- 0
tau_counter <- 0
missing <- 0
for (i in 1:length(ages)){
  age_counter <- age_counter + 1
  if (!is.null(taus[i])){
    tau_counter <- tau_counter + 1
  } else {
    cat(paste("Tau",i,"does not exist\n"))
    missing <- missing + 1
  }
}

cat(paste("Number of age values according to for loop:",age_counter))
#Number of age values according to for loop: 6078

cat(paste("Number of tau values according to for loop:",tau_counter))
#Number of tau values according to for loop: 6078

cat(paste("Missing values:",missing))
#Missing values: 0
```

This method says both vectors have the same lengths. Perhaps there is some better way of checking why the lengths differ?

Comment: I would suggest go back 1 step and debug why the length of `ages` and `taus` is different when you expected it to be same? From where do you get those vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be posible to have `NULL` in a `vector` unless it is a `list`.  If we change to `is.na`, it may work (assuming the missing values are `NA`

```
if (!is.na(taus[i])
```

i.e.

```
 !is.null(NA)
 #[1] TRUE
```

for each of the elements, thus giving the same number at the end for both `vector`s.  Also, note that the OP is looping over the length of the largest vector.  So, it is anyway adding 1 to all the elements